# Name of key in React.js for unselectable css

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I defined a css object inside of my render method but I am trying to figure out how to make text unselectable.  React.js has their own key names like backgroundColor instead of background-color for css objects.  I am trying to figure out key name for unselectable styles?  Example:

```js
 render:function(){
  var ListItems={
   cursor:'pointer',
   color:'black',
   marginLeft:'-20px',
   marginTop:'-10px',
   marginBottom:'14px',
   userSelect:'none',
  }
  if(this.state.linkHover=='hoverLink'){
   ListItems.color='blue';
  }else{
   ListItems.color='black';
  }
   return (
    <div>
    <li style={ListItems} onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave} onClick={this.onClick}><input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked} unselectable="on"/>{this.props.value}</li>
    </div>
   )
 }
```

userSelect doesn't seem to work in Chrome.  Is there a different name?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

user-select has the following css names:

```
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
```

According to this, react's names are:

```
MozUserSelect: "none"
WebkitUserSelect: "none"
msUserSelect: "none"
```

Every hyphen `-` and the following character is replaced by according uppercase letter.

Comment: The above answer is all correct except for `MsUserSelect` should be `msUserSelect`.

For reference:
https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html

Comment: The answer seems to be incorrect for me. This only works when I put "none" in quotations, as in: `MozUserSelect: "none"`